# Prove that the function's derivative is continuous for x>0

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^{2}x}$$

I think that its derivative is not really continuous, as the question might suggest. The derivative of $$ e^{-n^{2}x}$$ is  $$-n^{2}e^{-n^{2}x}$$
And the sum of the above function would be divergent in $$x= \frac{1}{n^{2}}$$
Could you please correct me, if I am wrong?

Comment: $n$ is a dummy variable. $x=\dfrac1{n^2}$ makes no sense.

Comment: So how do you prove it is, in fact, continuous? And if for some reason some function of similiar construction wasn't continuous, how could one prove it?

Comment: It's infinitely differentiable for $x>0$, but of course the series diverges for $x\le0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
the series is easily seen to be convergent for every $x>0$.
Moreover, you can prove that the series of derivatives is uniformly convergent on every compact interval $[a,b]\subset (0, +\infty)$, so that $F$ is continuously differentiable on those intervals.
But this implies that $F$ is continuously differentiable in $(0,+\infty)$.
(Given any point $x_0 > 0$, it is enough to apply the above reasoning on a compact interval $[a,b]$ with $0 < a < x_0 < b$.)